# Transformar una propiedad de todos los Json en un Array de Json. Angular/Typescript

Tags: array, json, typescript, date, angular13

Haciendo un programa tipo banco que hace unas llamadas a BBDD para listar una serie de transferencias que se realizan recibo un Array de Json con las propiedades "'transferDate', 'destination_account', 'amount', 'token address', 'status'" el problema es que dentro de los Json la propiedad transferDate viene expresada en milisegundos y para transformarla necesito aplicarle la función de Ts Date() pero la forma en que contruyo las tablas es la siguiente:

```
                 <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th *ngFor="let header of headers" id="{{header}}">
                            {{header}}
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tabla-movimientos">
                    <tr *ngFor="let transfer of transfers">
                        <td *ngFor="let header of headers">
                            {{transfer[header]}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

No se me ocurre de que forma aplicarle la conversión date() a las propiedades transferDate de cada Json del arreglo. El arreglo se ve así:

```
0:
amount: "45"
destination_account: 3
origin_account: 1
status: "R"
token_address: "-"
transferDate: 1648677600000
transferHash: 4
1:
amount: "1"
destination_account: 2
origin_account: 1
status: "P"
token_address: "-"
transferDate: 1648677600000
transferHash: 5
2:
amount: "25"
destination_account: 3
origin_account: 1
status: "P"
token_address: "-"
transferDate: 1648764000000
transferHash: 6
```

sin embargo el arreglo viene así de la bbdd y lo uso para construir las tablas según se guarda la variable de forma reactiva.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que podrías hacerlo con una función que compruebe el header procesado y si es el transferDate, entonces lo formateas. Algo así, cambia el siguiente código en el html

```
{{transfer[header]}}
```

por este otro

```
{{procesar(transfer[header], header)}}
```

Luego, en tu fichero .ts crea la función de esta manera

```
procesar(valor, hd):string{
    if(hd != 'transferDate') return valor;

    var d = new Date(valor);

    // Formatea aquí la fecha en el formato que desees
    return d.toDateString();
 }
```

Cambia el formateo de la fecha al formato que desees mostrar.